# assign the condition of the if statement to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have a long snippet of code and i am trying to shorten it.
This is what I have now:

```
statuses = cleaned_data.get("statuses")
if statuses:
    for status in statuses:
        ...
```

it would be nice if i can assign the value of `cleaned_data.get("statuses")` inside the if condition, like this: 
`if cleaned_data.get("statuses") as statuses` 
and carry on. 
Is it doable in python?

Comment: What do you want to do in the for-loop?

Comment: `for status in cleaned_data.get('statuses', []): ...`…?

Comment: @deceze nice idea. but what if i want to do something if the condition fails? using for else will not work as the else is reached in the last iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Assignment Expression (a.k.a walrus operator)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/):

```
if statuses := cleaned_data.get("statuses"):
    for status in statuses:
```

Comment: Can be shortened to `for status in statuses := cleaned_data.get("statuses", []):`

Comment: You are probably right, but without knowing what `cleaned_data.get("statuses")` is, I am hesitant to make this statement, as the object can be Falsey but still iterable upon.

Comment: Good point, best to keep bugs like those out.